# EditText in customPreference is not getting focused

Tags: android, android-settings

Created a customPreference in settings in which summary is "EditText" field. When it is clicked , view scrolls up for the keyboard  and editText is not getting focussed. How to focus editText?

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Also add edittext properties :

```
 android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode ="true"
```

and  `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

to outer layout that is getting scrolled.

Comment: can't set android:descendantFocusability in preference.